# c# Call delegate with runtime generic types

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, delegation

I have a delegate that I have created in runtime because I don't know its parameter types in design time. The code is the following:

```
var delegMethodType = typeof(Func<,,,>).MakeGenericType(type1, type2, type3, returnType);
```

As you can see I'm using Func<,,,> to represent Func<T1, T2, T3, TReturn>. It works perfectly.

After that, I create my delegate in this way:

```
var deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegMethodType, obj, methodInfo);
```

Where "delegMethodType" is the type for the delegate that I created before, "obj" is the object that receives the call, and "methodInfo" is the reflection method for "obj". This works perfectly.

Now, I need to call the delegate but due to "Delegate.CreateDelegate" returns a basic delegate, I cannot call it with the parameters:

```
// due to this delegate was created in runtime VS.NET doesn't recognize
// that the delegate allows three parameters and returns a value
var result = deleg(val1, val2, val3);
```

I can use the delegate with "deleg.DynamicInvoke()" but it's slow than calling the delegate with its parameters.

How I can call this delegate with three parameters and get its return value?

Comment: Unless you can constrain the types of the parameters then you have to use reflection. How slow is this already? Perhaps you should use a compiled `Expression` or a dynamic method

Comment: A little bit of testing shows that calling `Invoke` on a cached `delegMethodType.GetMethod("Invoke")` is actually faster, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/VgJpqo. Moral of the story: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to just invoke the methodInfo directly, or somewhat more complicatedly use the Linq Expressions library to create a `Func<object,object,...>` that can be invoked that does all of the required casts.

Note that I am assuming that you do know the number of parameters at compile time, as your question indicates with the `Func<,,,>` usage.

It's a bit involved, but basically comes down to using `Expression.Lambda(...).Compile()` to create the final func that will be invoked, `Expression.Convert()` to cast from objects to the actual types so that `Expression.Call()` can be used to call the method on objects with the correct types from our object `Expression.Parameter`s

This example shows how to implement both approaches.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SO
{
    class SO69847110
    {
        public TR fn<T1,T2,T3,TR>(T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3)
        {
            if(typeof(TR) == typeof(string))
            {
                return (TR)(object)"Hello World";
            }
            return default(TR);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var returnType = typeof(string);
            var paramType = typeof(int);
            var delegMethodType = typeof(Func<,,,>).
                MakeGenericType(
                    paramType,
                    paramType,
                    paramType,
                    returnType
                );
            var methodInfo = typeof(SO69847110).GetMethod("fn")
                .MakeGenericMethod(
                    paramType,
                    paramType,
                    paramType,
                    returnType
                );

            var obj = new SO69847110();

            //var deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegMethodType, obj, methodInfo);

            var methodInfoInvoke = methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { 0, 1, 2 });
            Console.WriteLine(methodInfoInvoke);

            var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
            var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
            var param3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
            var convertedParameterExpressions =
            new Expression[]
            {
                Expression.Convert(param1,paramType),
                Expression.Convert(param2,paramType),
                Expression.Convert(param3,paramType),
            };

            var expressed = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object, object, object>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(obj), obj.GetType()),
                    methodInfo,
                    convertedParameterExpressions
                ),
                tailCall:false,
                parameters: new[]
                {
                    param1,
                    param2,
                    param3
                }
                ).Compile();

            var expressedInvoked = expressed.Invoke(obj, 0, 1, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(expressedInvoked);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to call the same function for multiple objects, then you can also make the subject a `Func` parameter too - just make it a separate `Expression.Parameter(typeof(object))` at the start, include that parameter instead of the `Expression.Constant` and also include in the list of parameters for `Expression.Lambda`. Then also pass in the subject as a parameter when invoking.